# Invalid token 'while' in class, struct, or interface member declaratio

Tags: c#, oop, object, while-loop

I have the following code

```
class Card
{
    string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int KaLP = 8000;
        int YuLP = 8000;
        Card bewd = new Card();
        Card LOD = new Card();
        var KaibaDeck = new List<Card>() { bewd, LOD };
        var KaibaHand = new List<Card>() { };
        var KaibaFusionDeck = new List<Card>() { };
        var KaibaGraveyard = new List<Card>() { };
        var YugiDeck = new List<Card>() {  };
        var YugiHand = new List<Card>() { };
        var YugiFusionDeck = new List<Card>() { };
        var YugiGraveyard = new List<Card>() { };

        int KaibaDeckSize = KaibaDeck.Count;
        string sDrawChoice;
        int DrawChoice;
        while (KaibaDeckSize > 0)
        {
            if (DrawChoice == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                KaibaBattlePhase(KaibaHand, KaibaDeck, KaibaFusionDeck, YugiDeck, Field, KaibaGraveyard, YugiGraveyard, KaLP, YuLP, "Battle");
            }
        }
    }


    public static void KaibaBattlePhase(List<Card> KaibaHand, List<Card> KaibaDeck, List<Card> KaibaFusionDeck, List<Card> YugiDeck, List< List<Card> > Field, List<Card> KaibaGraveyard, List<Card> YugiGraveyard, int KaLP, int YuLP, const string Phase)
    {
        string sDecision;
        int Decision;

        while(true)//so the while loop NEVER breaks unless you have a 'break' later on
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to continue the Battle Phase? (Yes-'1'  No-'0', Check Kaiba's Graveyard '-1', Check YUGI's graveyard '-2')");
            sDecision = Console.ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(sDecision, out Decision);
            if (Decision==0)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (Decision==-1)
            {
                 KaibaGraveyardFunction(KaibaGraveyard);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void KaibaGraveyardFunction(List<Card> KaibaGraveyard)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Kaiba's graveyard contains: ");
        foreach (Card KG in KaibaGraveyard)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(KG.Name);

        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:
On the line `KaibaGraveyardFunction(KaibaGraveyard);`:

> Method must have a return type

At `while(true)`:

> Invalid token 'while' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

In addition, I'm getting alot of other errors such as 
"Invalid token '(', '=', '.' in class, struct, or interface member declaration"

"Syntax error, ']' expected"

Answer (score 3):

At the end of your method declaration for `KaibaBattlePhase` you have this method parameter:

```
const string Phase
```

That's a syntax error which is confusing the compiler and causing it to not understand pretty much anything afterward.  (I've never seen it get *that* confused from a keyword, usually that happens with missing/extra curly braces and such.  But I guess this triggers it too.)

Why are you trying to pass a *constant* as a method parameter?  That doesn't really make a lot of sense.  If the method thinks it's a constant, it won't accept any value for it.  If you pass it a constant, the method wouldn't know or care where the value came from.

If you remove `const` then the rest of the errors go away.

(Side note: The error becomes a *lot* easier to see if you clean up that method declaration.  10 parameters is *a lot*.  It's highly likely that you can get away with some refactoring there to make it a lot cleaner.  At its simplest, you can replace all of those parameters with a parameter DTO object which has those as properties.  Potentially more useful would be the [Replace Method With Method Object](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceMethodWithMethodObject.html) pattern, illustrated [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Emyyp8giuf0).)

Answer (score 0):

Not completely following your logic and not sure this is your issue but you never reevaluate `KaibaDeckSize`. If your intention is to simply use the `while (KaibaDeckSize > 0) {}` evaluation as a condition of entering the block, consider replacing it with a simple `if` statement: `if (KaibaDeckSize > 0) {}` Also, you never initialize `DrawChoice` which will generate a `Use of unassigned local variable` error during compilation. Use: `int DrawChoice = 0;` And this DrawCount` is never reassigned either.

**Did you actually post your most recent code?**

```
int KaibaDeckSize = KaibaDeck.Count;
string sDrawChoice;
int DrawChoice = 0;
while (KaibaDeckSize > 0)
{
    if (DrawChoice == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        KaibaBattlePhase(KaibaHand, KaibaDeck, 
            KaibaFusionDeck, YugiDeck, Field,
            KaibaGraveyard, YugiGraveyard, KaLP, YuLP, "Battle");
    }

    KaibaDeckSize = KaibaDeck.Count;
}
```